# Show Office 365 alias email as recepient in e-mail client

Tags: exchange, outlook, microsoft-office-365

When creating a new (shared)mailbox to Office 365 with a primary email address, you have the option to add multiple alias email addresses too.
When sending an email to one of these alias addresses, the recepient will always see the primary email address as the address the mail was sent to in his email client (for example Outlook).
If you want to see to which alias the email was actually sent, you have to look into the email header.

So the question is: is there a way to show the alias instead of the primary email address for incoming mails in the email client?

Comment: That's pretty much how it is with Exchange servers. One option with Outlook is to add filters that moves messages to different folders based on the original recipient address.

Answer (score 0):

Find the following similar cases for your reference:

[Exchange 2010 - Retaining the 'alias' in the 'To:' field after the message is delivered (for rules, routing, etc.)](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/821f4857-ae33-4e38-a0f2-758eabea6621/exchange-2010-retaining-the-alias-in-the-to-field-after-the-message-is-delivered-for-rules?forum=exchange2010)

[emails sent internally to alias address doesn't have proper To: address](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/462965-emails-sent-internally-to-alias-address-doesn-t-have-proper-to-address)